# I save data using coreData but yet objects stay nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I am using core data to save information to objects, but when I try to use it the program crashed and says "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

This is the data which I generate

```
func generateTestData()
{
    let item = Item(context: context)
    item.title = "New Iphone 7s"
    item.price = 2000
    item.details = "I wish it's something that is worth to apple , unline Iphone 7"


    let item2 = Item(context: context)
    item2.title = "Beach House in France"
    item2.price = 3000000
    item2.details = "I will live there for the rest of my Life , untill then i don't have a life"
}
```

this is the fetch function

```
func attemptFetch()
{
    let fetchRequest :NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
    let datasort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "created", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [datasort]
    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    self.controller = controller

    do{
       try controller.performFetch()
    }
    catch{
        let error = error as NSError
        print(error.debugDescription)
    }
}
```

the crash happens here when i try to update my view

```
 func configureCell(cell : objectItemCell , indexPath :IndexPath)
{
    let item  = controller.object(at:indexPath)
    cell.configureCell(item: item)
}
```

UITableViewCell class

```
func configureCell(item : Item)
{
    self.title.text = item.title
    self.price.text = "$\(item.price)"
    self.details.text = item.details
}
```

Comment: It means that something is nil. Try to find which property is nil, which line exactly is causing the crash.

Comment: the that says self.title.text = item.title , and same goes for the rest down

Comment: But does it mean that `item` is nil? That `item.title` is nil, or that `self.title` is nil? That's different case, whether the issue is on the CoreData side or in your Cell side.

Comment: i just found that my outlets weren't connect ! Thanks man for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

Before fetching data from item, Please save context. In your scenario, in generateTestData(), do context.save(), may be your app is crashing because you are not saving data and trying to fetch which returns nil,

```
func generateTestData()
{
let item = Item(context: context)
item.title = "New Iphone 7s"
item.price = 2000
item.details = "I wish it's something that is worth to apple , unline Iphone 7"


let item2 = Item(context: context)
item2.title = "Beach House in France"
item2.price = 3000000
item2.details = "I will live there for the rest of my Life , untill then i don't have a life"
saveContext() // save data that you initialised
}

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support
func saveContext () {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Still crashes , when i debug the data is saved but when i try to use it it crashes

Answer (score 0):

As far as Core data in iOS is concerned, when you use your generateTestData(), the data is created in NSManagedObjectContext. Just because it resides in the NSManagedObjectContext doesn't mean it gets saved in SQLite.

[image]

To save data into SQLite (required for persistence so you don't have to run generateTestData() every time), use

```
ad.saveContext()
```

The saveContext() is like a commit statement in db terms. In order to use the above, declare the following in your AppDeligate.swift outside the class definition so you can access your context across in your controllers.

```
let ad = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let contextAP = ad.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

> NOTE : Doing the above saves the data in SQLite but running generateTestData() twice with same data with saveContext() will create duplicate records in your SQLite.

Image Reference : https://www.objc.io/images/issue-4/stack-simple-9af1e89d.png

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to create a managedObjectContext in the class where you try to fetch your objects/entitys

```
import CoreData

sampleClass: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource ... {

    var context: NSManagedObjectContext!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! UIAppDelegate
       context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }

    funcAttemptFetch() {
        // your code
    }
```

hopefully this would help you